# Fancybox only firing on first gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I am using a foreach loop inside of wordpress to give each image's < rel > tag the value of the `$post_ID`. I am also creating a data variable called 'gallery' with a value of the `$post_ID`. I am then using fancybox to call upon my data variable and fire fancybox.

This all works perfect for the first image gallery, but when I go to the next one it doesn't fire fancybox even though the data value and rel tag values match up on the next galleries.

My jQuery:

```
var galleryvalue = $('.portfolio-gallery').data('gallery');

$("a[rel=" + galleryvalue + "]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'cyclic'        : true,
    'autoScale'     : true,
    'showNavArrows'     : true,
    'overlayColor'      : '#666'

    });
```

My html:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
); ?>

<?php $images = get_posts( $args );
$imageclass = array( 'class' => "gallery-image");

if (!empty($images)) { 
    foreach($images as $image): ?>
        <a rel="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="portfolio-gallery" data-gallery="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID, 'large' ); ?> " title="" >
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'singles_thumb', '' ,$imageclass); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Any ideas as to why fancybox is only working on the first gallery? Fancybox in my jQuery should be looking for different rel tags to start each gallery so I know I'm doubling up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem. The problem was with what fancybox was using to fire.

Changing to fireing fancybox with a class instead of using a < rel > tag was the trick.

```
$('a.portfolio-gallery').fancybox({
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'cyclic'        : true,
    'autoScale'     : true,
    'showNavArrows'     : true,
    'overlayColor'      : '#666'            
});
```

And by making my < rel > tag a different value using the post->ID, makes fancybox see that my class of portfolio-gallery is clicked. And then recognizes that each < rel > tag is a different gallery.

```
<a rel="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="portfolio-gallery" data-gallery="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID, 'large' ); ?> " title="" >
    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'singles_thumb', '' ,$imageclass); ?>
</a>
```

I found in the info on the fancybox http://fancybox.net/howto page. So my answer was quite simple...I was just over thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

even if it is not really and answer - I can not add a comment :
Is your aim to have MULTIPLE galleries on one page ?

Btw - Your images will all have the same rel - Is that what you want ? ..

It might be helpfull to trigger fancybox directly on the images -
This is how I usually do it for wordpress :

```
    //***  START FancyBOX   -->
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */
    jQuery('.gallery-icon a,.wp-caption a,.wp-caption-text').attr('rel', 'fancygallery')
     //* use the following add class dynamically with jQuery
    //** jQuery('.gallery-icon a').addClass('fancybox').attr('rel','gallery')  
    jQuery(".gallery-icon a").fancybox({
        'my_options_here'   :   'elastic',

    });
    jQuery(".wp-caption a").fancybox({
        'my_options_here'   :   'elastic',

    });
});
```

Comment: I had something similar to this without positive results. I'm using Flexslider for a main image, and then fancybox image gallery inside the caption area of flexslider to create a thumbnail gallery. I'ts pretty wild. lol. I actually found an answer I'll post here in a second.

Comment: well. i am glad it works . your solution that you posted is exactly what I wrote - but nevermind.